# Question about sorting by date inside a database using Django

Tags: python, django, database

I have a database, in which it's possible to find products by their name. The DB has ID, category, name, amount and date defined, and I was trying to create a separate search field that would let me search those items by the date they were added.

The models.py looks like this:

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date', '-pk')

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.date} {self.name} {self.amount}'
```

And views.py looks like this:

```
class ExpenseListView(ListView):
    model = Expense
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):

        queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list

        form = ExpenseSearchForm(self.request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():

            name = form.cleaned_data.get('name', '').strip()
            if name:
                queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=name)

        return super().get_context_data(
            form=form,
            object_list=queryset,
            summary_per_category=summary_per_category(queryset),
            **kwargs)
```

I've added the "date" field under the "name", following it's structure, but I kept getting the 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'strip' error. Is there a different format for defining the date? When I've also added it to the search field in forms.py, it was seen there as a string.

I've also found a similar post from [How to make date range filter in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732078/how-to-make-date-range-filter-in-django), but it didn't explained that much, even after searching in the official library. I'm very new to Django, and I'm not sure if there should be a separate queryset call out for searching by date too.

In form.is_valid() I've tried to add the date field, but I kept getting the 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'strip' error.

Comment: I'm not sure its related to your question but I notice you might be misunderstanding the usage of the `db_index=True` kwarg of a model field. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596176/when-we-should-use-db-index-true-in-django

Answer (score 0):

I think the behaviour you're looking for is described I. The django documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now

#### DateField

```
field_name = DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, **options)
```

A date, represented in Python by a datetime.date instance. Has a few extra, optional arguments:

##### DateField.auto_now

Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved. Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.

The field is only automatically updated when calling `Model.save()`. The field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways such as `QuerySet.update()`, though you can specify a custom value for the field in an update like that.

##### DateField.auto_now_add

Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored. If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of `auto_now_add=True`:

##### For DateField:

```
default=date.today - from datetime.date.today()
```

##### For DateTimeField:

```
default=timezone.now - from django.utils.timezone.now()
```

The default form widget for this field is a `DateInput`. The admin adds a JavaScript calendar, and a shortcut for “Today”. Includes an additional `invalid_date` error message key.